# Does this partition of an indexed union have a standard name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let

1. $\mathscr{I}$ be an arbitrary index set, and $\{A_i : i \in \mathscr{I}\}$ be a family of sets indexed on $\mathscr{I}$;
2. $U = \bigcup_{i \in \mathscr{I}} A_i$;
3. $\phi: U \to \{0, 1\}^\mathscr{I}, x \mapsto b$, such that
   $
     b_i =
   \begin{cases}
   0,  & \text{if $x \notin A_i$}, \\
   1,  & \text{if $x \in A_i$};
   \end{cases}
   $ 
   and
4. $U/\phi$ be the quotient set induced by $\phi$ on $U$; IOW, $U/\phi = \{\phi^{-1}(J) \mid J \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi) \}$.

Informally, the "vector"<sup>1</sup> $\phi(x)$ encodes the "membership status" of $x \in U$ with respect to the component sets $A_i$, and $U/\phi$ is the coarsest partition of $U$ for which this membership status vector is constant in each class of the partition.

My question is: is there a standard name for the partition $U/\phi$ as defined above?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I put scare-quotes around the term *vector* here because I'm not sure that it is appropriate when $\mathscr{I}$ is not countable.</sup>

Comment: Sometimes that partition is called the kernel of the mapping $\phi$, but that seems to fall short of answering the entire question. $\qquad$

Comment: I’m not aware of one. I’d call it the partition of $U$ generated by the family $\{A_i:i\in\mathscr{I}\}$.